# Permanently Disable Address Bar Blackberry Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

How can I permanently disable or hide the address bar of the mobile browser via my application. Does jquery mobile have and option or is there any other way? Here is the event I am using to initially load up my page. Its only a one page application that will only be seen in a blackberry native browser (no other mobile device)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind('pageinit', function (event) {
       //loads the applications html into the DOM
        loadHomePage();   
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can scroll the page so that the address bar is hidden, but you can't disable the address bar.

Comment: So you are telling me there is no way to hide the address without scrolling first? Its impossible?

Comment: Nothing is impossible but think about the implementations of allowing webpages to disable the browser itself (or parts of the browser). Popups would have their way with us.